# Google new permission issue

Tags: android, codeigniter, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

I developed an App in ionic 3 and was also live on google play.

But due to some google policy changes my application got remove from playstore. Now i uploaded the app multiple times with new policy update but still my app is getting rejected.

I am not using any default sms handler or not using any call feature. I am using third party SMS api for mobile no. verification. I am using Razorpay payment gateway and i found that to remove sms permission from this plugin. and i did the same, but no effect. again app got rejected from google.

Now i need help if anyone has any idea about what changes i need to do to publish my app.

Backend api in Codeigniter.

Comment: You'll have to read very carefully why your app was removed and then make changes to your app yourself. Nobody except that email and Google employee would be able to help you unless you add why your app was actually removed.

Comment: Sorry but there is no information why my app got rejected. Thats why i am unable to trouble shoot what should i change in my app.

Comment: They must have issued an email telling you what led to the deletion.